# Enter the same data into multiple, non-adjacent cells in OpenOffice.Org Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I want to enter the same data into multiple cells that are not adjacent.
I have selected the cells and pressed CTRL + ENTER but this doesn't work.

Comment: Copy the data to the clip board, select the cells and press 'Ctrl+V'.

Comment: `OpenOffice.org` is outdated.  Are you asking about Apache OpenOffice or LibreOffice?

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you can't do this for non-adjacent cells in OpenOffice or LibreOffice Calc (this is different from Excel - there, you can use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on non-contiguous ranges). For adjacent cells, use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to enter data or formula into all selected cells. Works both in OpenOffice Calc and LibreOffice Calc.

From the LibreOffice Calc Help (https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Shortcut_Keys_for_Spreadsheets):

> To fill a selected cell range with the formula that you entered on the Input line, press Alt+Enter.

Answer (score 2):

There does not seem to be any way to select multiple nonadjacent cells and then type in a value to fill all cells.  Using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> gives the following message.

```
Insert into multiple selection not possible.
```

Instead, in LibreOffice, first enter the value into a single cell, then copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or the menu).  After that, select multiple nonadjacent cells and paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> or the menu).

Paste multiple does not work in Apache OpenOffice.  However a macro could be written and assigned to a hotkey.  Here is some code to get started.

```vb
Sub DisplaySelectedRanges
    oSels = ThisComponent.CurrentSelection
    For selIndex = 0 to oSels.getCount() - 1
        oSel = oSels.getByIndex(selIndex)
        Print(oSel.AbsoluteName)
    Next selIndex
End Sub
```